# Can I have both front-page.php and index.php?

Tags: templates, frontpage

I've made a custom front-page.php which includes "the loop" and it works great. I would also like to have a separate page which is the regular old posts page you get from index.php. How do I make a page refer to index.php?

I've tried going to Appearance -> Customize and setting a static front page, but then "the loop" on my main page stops working, so that's not the solution.

Comment: Have you studied the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)? Do you fully understand [the difference between the front page, the home page, and the `index.php` template file](http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/)? Have you properly set up your [static front page and your posts page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)?

Answer (score 3):

When a theme has the `front-page.php` template, it will take over regardless of what you set in the admin pages to be your front page. [<sup>1</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Configuration_of_front-page.php) This means you have a couple of options:

1. Create a page template with your loop and styles that are currently part of `front-page.php`, apply that template to a new page you create in WP, then assign that new page to be your static front page in the Admin settings (Settings → Reading → Front page displays → Front page).
   Then create a page with your regular loop and styles for your blog index page, assign it to a new page in WP, and set it as the front page for your blog posts (Settings → Reading → Front page displays → Posts page).
2. Consider adding the `home.php` template to the mix so that it handles the "regular old posts page." [<sup>2</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display)

I'd recommend #2, since it avoids having to create 2 more pages inside WP that are just there to trigger the template files. Since the loader already looks for the `front-page.php` and `home.php` templates, those pages will load faster if the templates are in there and used properly.

#### UPDATED 1/16

Okay, here's a bit more background...

- If you have the `front-page.php` template **and** "Your latest posts" selected, the home page of your site will use the `front-page.php` template.
- If you have the `front-page.php` template **and** `home.php` **and** "A static page (Front page)" selected **but** nothing selected for "Posts page", the home page of your site will use the content of the page you selected with the `front-page.php` template and `index.php` for posts (ignoring `home.php`).
- If you have the `front-page.php` template **and** `home.php` **and** "A static page (Front page)" selected **and** a "Posts page" selected, the home page of your site will use the content of the page you selected with the `front-page.php` template, and the content of the page you selected with the `home.php` template.

It can get a bit complex, especially since there's so much flexibility involved. It was something I had to go back and play with again just to refresh my understanding.

The main purpose is to have something distinct on the front page (completely different layout, different colors, different header, etc.) while having the option to swap out the home page content just by selecting the page you want to use. You can also have the main blog page slightly different than the rest of your single posts or pages, which is where the `home.php` comes into play.

#### /update

#### Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page
- http://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: Using `home.php` is the way to go here. Note that merely having `index.php` is also sufficient, since the home page template (i.e. the blog posts index) falls back from `home.php` to `index.php` per the Template Hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying and trying to make this work. So you say that the first step is to add home.php. I've done that, but I cant find a way to refer to home.php either. Mysite.com/home.php gives me a 404. I've scoured the docs, but I can't find any way to get to home.php except from the front page (which is where I have something else). I tried making home.php into a template but then it turns out that the loop doesn't work on templates. I'm amazed that it's so complicated to get a blog index page in Wordpress. I thought a blog index page would be standard.

Comment: The template files live inside your theme folder and aren't accessed directly through a URL, but are loaded by WordPress based on what kind of page is being displayed. In this case, the contents of `front-page.php` are displayed when your site's front page is loaded and `home.php` is displayed when your blog page is loaded (whatever page you set to display your blog posts). So if you have a page called "My Blog Posts", and have that set in the admin to display blog posts, then it will load the `home.php` template (which should have the loop and any other code you want to use to diplay posts).

Comment: But the admin only gives me the option to set a posts page if I set a static front page. And as per my original question, setting it to a static front page stops the loop from working on the front page.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I added to the confusion. I've updated my answer to help clarify things a bit more based on some testing I just completed.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is some customization, you wouldn't want default template to work.
What you can do is you can create a new template file that would request the type of posts you want and other options like orderby, number_of_posts etc. Simply put the code in a  new template file and assign the page that template.